# Change a layer order with mapscript

Tags: mapserver, mapscript

I'm very new with mapScript, I'm looking to change a layer order with mapScript. My ms_newMapObj is a merge of many mapfile so I don't know the index of the layer I want to move up.

I haven't find how to associate the layer with the drawing index given by `getLayersDrawingOrder`. This method returning only a list of index but what i realize, it's that the layer object haven't an index properties. I know the method  `moveLayerUp` but it needs an index in parameter too.

Here is my code to get the layer I want to move up.

```
 $allLayers = $oMapFinal->getAllLayerNames();

foreach ($allLayers as $evalLayer){
    $layer = $oMapFinal->getLayerByName($evalLayer);
    if($layer == MY CONDITION)
       //change drawing order
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it, it seems that getAllLayerNames and getLayersDrawingOrder have the same order.

So here is my code:

```
 $allLayers = $oMapFinal->getAllLayerNames();

foreach ($allLayers as $index => $evalLayer){
    $layer = $oMapFinal->getLayerByName($evalLayer);
    if($layer == MY CONDITION) {
       $arrLayOrder = $oMapFinal->getLayersDrawingOrder();
       unset($arrLayOrder[$index]);
       $oMapFinal->setLayersDrawingOrder(array_merge([$index],$arrLayOrder));
    }
}
```